# How to obtain the next route's path in an Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am catching all traffic before passing it forward using:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    ... run before stuff, related to the next req.route.path
    next();
});
```

and I want to run some code before calling the `next()` function.
in order for me to know the proper code I need to run, I have to identify what is the next request route path.

Debugging current req object (inside all('*',.. ) does not giving any information about the next `request.route.path`

How can I get the next method route.path before calling it?

Your help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The next route is simply the next matching route. Routes higher up are tested against first, and so routes lower down are tested last.

Comment: ok, so next is not the correct word for what i need, how can i know the target route path, the original path, with out the parameters inside it, i mean /user/:user_id/user_attr:user_attr ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to look ahead, why not explicitly set middleware for the routes that need it?

```
var middleware = function (req, res, next) {
  ..run your code in here
};

app.get('/users:user_id', middleware, function(req, res, next) {

});
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, i will try this approach :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the next route by checking the route when the response in the middleware has fired the `finish` event:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('Next route: ', req.route.path);
  });
  next();
});
```

For a route defined like this:

```
app.get('/users/:user_id', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello');
});
```

You'll obtain the log:

> $ Next route: '/users/:user_id'

Comment: hey great solution, i learned something, the thing is i want to run an kind of filter/before for specific entries,  this will be great for implementing the "after" filter thank you